# Loading data from a query to Big Query with Google Apps Script - Required Parameter is missing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am trying to use the following code in order to insert data into Big Query. However, I get the error "Required Parameter is missing".

```
function runQuery() {

  var projectId = 'xxxxxxx';
  var datasetId = 'Registration_Funnel_Test';
  var tableId = 'reg_funnel_test_';
  var date = '2015-11-05';
  var tableDate = date.split('-').join('');

  var bigQueryQuery = {
    query: 'SELECT'+ 
    'date,'+
    'CONCAT([fullVisitorId], STRING([visitId])) as sessionId,'+
     'hits.eventInfo.eventAction as event_action,'+
    'FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([82514188.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP("'+date+'"),'
        TIMESTAMP("'+date+'"))) '+
    'WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventAction IN ("Started Registration",'+
     "Completed Registration","Made First Deposit")'+
     'GROUP EACH BY date, sessionId, event_action;'            
          };
    var job = {
        configuration: {
          query: {
            query: bigQueryQuery,
            destinationTable: {
              projectId: projectId,
              datasetId: datasetId,
              tableId: tableId+tableDate
            },
            'allowLargeResults': true,
            'createDisposition': 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
            'writeDisposition': 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
          }
        }
      };
      var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
      Logger.log(jobResult.status.state);
      Logger.log(jobResult.status);         
    }
```

The line of code throwing the error is `var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);`

Google documentation can be found here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert, but I just can't see the problem. I have a more complicated example that uses this approach and it works so I am out of options. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There seems tom be something strange with your code above ... the 'var bigQueryQuery {' line has an open brace but I don't see the corresponding closing one. It also looks like it is setting a 'query' field, but it should just be a string.

Comment: Thanks @JordanTigani. I amended the code error above by adding a closing brace. I will try just using a string now.

Comment: how did you create the projectId to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

check below line in destination table:

```
tableId: tableId+tableDate
```

Try to define tableId outside and then use

```
tableId: tableId
```

If this still doesn't work for you - I would recommend to execute manually similar (or same) query in Native BG UI an then using jobid check configuration that is issued. This way you will know for sure what itshould looks like in your case